# Geoprocessing all shapefiles of folder using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I have 200 shapefile in a folder. All of them are similar. I need to select by attribute then apply the Eliminate tool and save the shapefiles.

How do I do this automatically with all the feature classes using ModelBuilder?

Comment: As with any automation task the trick is to get one iteration working first. What does your model to process one shapefile look like?

Comment: Hi @PolyGeo. Thank you for your answer. I would like that the model open the shp one to one from the folder, iteration by the name file?. I don´t known how can i do.

Comment: iterate every shapefile in the folder.

Comment: here is a help doc- http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm

Comment: Thank you @NULL.Dude. I tried ot with Iterate Files but i can not connect output with the next step (Selec layer by atribute). I use connect icon but only can use precondition option. How can I upload a screenshot to show you?

Comment: [How to upload screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91716/215590)

Answer (score 1):

I would try the [Iterate Feature Classes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-classes.htm) tool which:

> Iterates over feature classes in a Workspace or Feature Dataset.

I have not tested but would assume that it will work on shapefiles within a folder workspace.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Iterate Files](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-files.htm) tool available for ModelBuilder which:

> Iterates over files in a folder.

Comment: Thank you @Roberto Santos. I tried it with Iterate Files but i can not connect output with the next step (Select layer by atribute). I use connect icon but only can use precondition option. How can I upload a screenshot to show you?

Comment: Hi, I think you can edit the question and add a figure there.

Comment: @jmonrealnunez Use iterate feature class instead.it works with shapefiles